# No Tools for Kdenlive

Tags: video, kdenlive

Hey guys I use kdenlive to edit videos and than upload them to youtube but recently I was exploring kdenlive, than somehow I don't know what I clicked that caused closing all the tools (like clip monitor). So now I can't watch the edited video and now my clip adder is gone. So now I can't even add a clip/movie to my project. I can't even make a video for youtube please help me!:( ***[image: emphasized text]***

As you can see there are no tools or anything all.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how this happened. If you could find its reason, let me know too. I need it.

But as solution, you must be able to reset the layout to the default by going to menu: View > Load layout > Layout 1.

If you cannot see menu bar, press ALT+F10

I hope it solve your problem